# Fetching documentation of ISymbol from MetadataReference

Tags: c#, roslyn, analysis, roslyn-code-analysis

I started learning about Roslyn Code Analysis recently. I went through provided sample codes. My question is following:

**Is there a way how to get XML documentation comment of a symbol loaded from a referenced library?**

Sample code I worked with is `FAQ(7)`. The goal is to get documentation comment of, let us say, a `Console.Write` function.

```
    public void GetWriteXmlComment()
    {
        var project1Id = ProjectId.CreateNewId();
        var document1Id = DocumentId.CreateNewId(project1Id);

        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location);

        var solution = new AdhocWorkspace().CurrentSolution
            .AddProject(project1Id, "Project1", "Project1", LanguageNames.CSharp)
            .AddMetadataReference(project1Id, mscorlib);

        var declarations = SymbolFinder.FindDeclarationsAsync(solution.Projects.First(), "Write", true).Result;

        var decFirst = declarations.First();
        var commentXml = decFirst.GetDocumentationCommentXml();
    }
```

The sample code works well for some methods - it gets the documentation text. But for methods, such as `Console.Write`, it uses `NullDocumentationProvider` and therefore returns empty string.

### UPDATE

I have found I can load the `MetadataReference` with `TestDocumentationProvider` instance as following:

```
        var mscorlib = MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(typeof(object).Assembly.Location,
            default(MetadataReferenceProperties), new TestDocumentationProvider());
```

where `TestDocumentationProvider` implements `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis DocumentationProvider` abstract class.

```
    private class TestDocumentationProvider : DocumentationProvider
    {
        protected override string GetDocumentationForSymbol(string documentationMemberID, CultureInfo preferredCulture, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken))
        {
            // To-Be-Done
        }
    }
```

Now the question narrows to **how to read documentation using `documentationMemberID`**?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update**: In Roslyn 2.0 you can use `XmlDocumentationProvider.CreateFromFile`.

---

The only way I can think of is using Reflection to create a `FileBasedXmlDocumentationProvider` (or otherwise copying its implementation from GitHub). You'll also need to search for the reference assemblies, since the load location of the framework assemblies does not contain documentation.

```
private static MetadataReference FromType(Type type)
{
    var path = type.Assembly.Location;
    return MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(path, documentation: GetDocumentationProvider(path));
}

private static string GetReferenceAssembliesPath()
{
    var programFiles =
        Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem
            ? Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86
            : Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFiles);
    var path = Path.Combine(programFiles, @"Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework");
    if (Directory.Exists(path))
    {
        var directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).OrderByDescending(Path.GetFileName);
        return directories.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    return null;
}

private static DocumentationProvider GetDocumentationProvider(string location)
{
    var referenceLocation = Path.ChangeExtension(location, "xml");
    if (File.Exists(referenceLocation))
    {
        return GetXmlDocumentationProvider(referenceLocation);
    }
    var referenceAssembliesPath = GetReferenceAssembliesPath();
    if (referenceAssembliesPath != null)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(location);
        referenceLocation = Path.ChangeExtension(Path.Combine(referenceAssembliesPath, fileName), "xml");
        if (File.Exists(referenceLocation))
        {
            return GetXmlDocumentationProvider(referenceLocation);
        }
    }
    return null;
}

private static DocumentationProvider GetXmlDocumentationProvider(string location)
{
    return (DocumentationProvider)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(
        "Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.FileBasedXmlDocumentationProvider, Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Workspaces.Desktop"),
        location);
}
```

I've used something similar in [RoslynPad](https://github.com/aelij/RoslynPad/blob/master/src/RoslynPad.Roslyn/RoslynHost.cs).

Comment: Oh, I did not know about these XML files under Reference Assemblies directory. Will try make it work using these files. Will post result if anyhow interesting. Thx 4 RoslynPad.

Comment: Feel free to file a bug on GitHub asking us to make that public, if you haven't already.